# Ruby on Rails, Devise: Force user to re-enter password for the specific pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm developing an app using Rails 4 and Devise for user's authentication. It's intended be used on the computers of our clients' storefront by their customers, and a user should always logged-in with each store's user account.

However, since there are some pages that we don't want customers to see, like `/admin`, we've decided that users have to re-enter password (only password, not both username and password) for the first time when visiting the specific pages even if they have already logged in.

How do you force user to re-enter password for the specific pages?

Comment: Define a re-authentication method in `ApplicationController` and use `before_filter` to run it for specific actions. If `session[:reauthenticated_at]` is recently modified, do nothing, otherwise redirect the user to reauthentication controller that will ask for password, verify with Devise (`current_user.password_digest && current_user.authenticate(params[:password])`) and set `session[:reauthenticated_at]` to `Time.now`

Comment: Thank you for the detailed instructions!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

{I am doing a similar app which is intended to support group activities.  So the leader logs in on each computer and the participants simply pick their user name.  to protect the leaders configuration pages I did the following

```
    before_action :re_authenticate,  only: [:admin_functions]
    private      
    def re_authenticate    
       authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic('Administration') { |username, password|
          username==current_user.username && current_user.valid_password?(password)
        }
   end
```

works well.  The user has to re-authenticate to access the admin pages, so the computers that they've login to for the class, don't have access without a second login.